# Chuwi Ubook X 2023 - ipu3-csi2 Webcams not working in ubuntu and debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, drivers, camera

I have bought the CHUWI Ubook X 2023 and as every reasonable person, the first thing I tried is installing linux on it.

As explained in other threads [Linux on the Ubook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605882/chuwi-ubook-x-installing-linux-fedora-or-ubuntu-resolving-intel-graphics-pr) main problems are graphic drivers and screen rotation although those are relatively easy to solve. Lid sensors, keyboard, pen etc all seem to work just fine. However, cameras are failing. I can't get none of them to work. They seem to be of type ipu3-csi2 cameras as this is the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices -D`

```
ipu3-imgu (PCI:0000:00:05.0):
/dev/video4
/dev/video5
/dev/video6
/dev/video7
/dev/video8
/dev/video9
/dev/video10
/dev/video11
/dev/video12
/dev/video13
/dev/media1

Intel IPU3 CIO2 (PCI:0000:00:14.3):
/dev/video0
/dev/video1
/dev/video2
/dev/video3
/dev/media0

Driver Info:
Driver name      : ipu3-cio2
Card type        : Intel IPU3 CIO2
Bus info         : PCI:0000:00:14.3
Driver version   : 6.5.3
Capabilities     : 0x84201000
    Video Capture Multiplanar
    Streaming
    Extended Pix Format
    Device Capabilities
Device Caps      : 0x04201000
    Video Capture Multiplanar
    Streaming
    Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
Driver name      : ipu3-cio2
Model            : Intel IPU3 CIO2
Serial           : 
Bus info         : PCI:0000:00:14.3
Media version    : 6.5.3
Hardware revision: 0x00000000 (0)
Driver version   : 6.5.3
Interface Info:
ID               : 0x03000006
Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
ID               : 0x00000004 (4)
Name             : ipu3-cio2 0
Function         : V4L2 I/O
Pad 0x01000005   : 0: Sink, Must Connect
  Link 0x02000008: from remote pad 0x1000003 of entity 'ipu3-csi2 0' (Video Interface Bridge): Data, Enabled, Immutable
```

Neither cheese nor qcam from libcamera manage to show any image from them. I know the device is not damaged as they work just fine in windows.